# Inserting data into tables without primary key?

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

I was surprised to know that SQL Server (I tested the 2008 R2 edition, but this seems to work in earlier versions too) allows inserting data into tables which do not have a primary key (and hence a clustered index) defined.

How is it possible and how the data are stored physically for these tables?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible? Such tables are called heaps.

Comment: Primary Key != Clustered Index. You can have a non clustered PK or a clustered index that isn't the PK.

Comment: And actually, it's not possible in Azure SQL Database (I think that's the current marketing name for SQL Azure) - you can't create a table without a primary key. But Martin is absolutely right, you don't need a PK to have a clustered index, and when you do have a PK, it doesn't have to be clustered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Helpful link here:

http://www.sqlmag.com/blog/sql-server-questions-answered-28/sql-server/what-happens-if-i-drop-a-clustered-index-137109

> Q: I’ve heard that the clustered index is “the data,” but I don’t
>   fully understand what that means. If I drop a clustered index, will I
>   lose the data?
>
> A: I get asked this question a lot, and I find that index structures
>   tend to confuse people; indexes seem mysterious and, as a result, are
>   unintentionally thought of as very complicated. A table can be stored
>   internally with or without a clustered index. If a table doesn’t have
>   a clustered index, it’s called a heap. If the table has a clustered
>   index, it’s often referred to as a clustered table. When a clustered
>   index is created, SQL Server will temporarily duplicate and sort the
>   data from the heap into the clustered index key order (because the key
>   defines the ordering of the data) and remove the original pages
>   associated with the heap. From this point forward, SQL Server will
>   maintain order logically through a doubly-linked list and a B+ tree
>   that’s used to navigate to specific points within the data.